# Removing blank elements from an array

Tags: regex, perl

In my Perl code, I am accessing an email. I need to fetch the table in it and parse it into an array.
I did it using:

```
my @plain = split(/\n/,$plaintext);
```

However, there are many blank elements in `@plain`. It has 572 elements and about half of them are empty.

Am I doing anything wrong here? What do I need to add/change in my code to get rid of the blank elements?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`grep` the output so you only get entries that contain non-whitepace characters.

```
my @plain = grep { /\S/ } split(/\n/,$plaintext);
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363981/removing-blank-elements-from-an-array/11365090#11365090) from @dave-cross

Quick and dirty if you're not up for fixing your split:

```
foreach(@plain){
    if( ( defined $_) and !($_ =~ /^$/ )){
        push(@new, $_);
    }
}
```

edit: how it works

There are going to be more elegant and efficient ways of doing it than the above, but as with everything perl-y tmtowtdi!  The way this works is:

1. Loop through the array `@plain`, making `$_` set to current array element

   `foreach(@plain){`
2. Check the current element to see if we're interested in it:

   `( defined $_) # has it had any value assigned to it
   !($_ =~ /^$/ ) # ignore those which have been assigned a blank value eg. ''`
3. If the current element passes those checks push it to @new

   `push(@new, $_);`

Comment: Sorry, that dint change the output.

Comment: After including that loop the array you'd need to use is '@new' if '@new' and '@plain' produce the same output then the elements which you thought were blank in @plain are not blank

Comment: That worked! I had done the same as you said in my previous attempt but I guess I missed something. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could tell me how that works.

Comment: `@new = grep { defined() and length() } @plain`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It works but every element has \n prefixed to it. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

One line addition is required in your code, and it works

```
   @plain= grep { $_ ne '' } @plain;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what i used, too late but this is good one , can be used in future

```
$t = "1.2,3.4,3.12,3.18,3.27";
my @to = split(',',$t);
foreach $t ( @to ){
    push ( @valid , $t );
}
my $max = (sort { $b <=> $a } @valid)[0];
print $max
```

Comment: Are you answering the right question here? The original question was about filtering out empty elements from an array and you do nothing like that. And the original question said nothing about finding the maximum value in the array. Also, why do you copy `@to` into `@valid` in such an inefficient manner?